# event processing in dojo surface

Tags: event-handling, dojo, dojox.gfx

I have a surface where i draw some kind of dynamic image based on the data from my backend, on click of a certain area, i want different data to be published. but my following code always takes last data drawn to publish.

```
function renderICD() {
    var totalx=1200;
    var totaly=1000;
    var xOffset = 150;
    var yOffset = 20;

    surface = dojox.gfx.createSurface("icdTab",totalx+2,totaly+2);
    var grid = surface.createGroup();
    var step = 1;
    var xyHolder = {};
    var group = grid.createGroup();

    for(var ii=0;ii<2;ii++)
    {
         var x = (step-1) * (75+85);
         step++;

         var group = grid.createGroup();

         group.createRect({x:xOffset+x+33, y:yOffset+20+90, width: 10, height: 10}).setFill([255, 255, 255, 0.9])
            .setStroke({color:'black' , width:2});


              dojo.connect(group.getEventSource(),"onclick",function(e) {
                       var internal = ii;
                       alert("publishing "+internal);
               //shape was clicked, now do something!
                        });

         grid.createText({x:xOffset+x+33, y:yOffset+20+80, text:ii,align:"middle"})
            .setFill('red')
            .setFont({size: '10px',weight: "bold"});
    }
}
```

As i understand, only 1 instance of function written to handle event is present, but what i am trying to handle is 2 different events. 
How can i achieve this?

[image: Snapshot of surface with 2 rects, when i click on both rects, i get '2' in my alert.]

Snapshot of surface with 2 rects, when i click on both rects, i get '2' in my alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has functional scope, not block scope, so you only have one `ii` variable, which is always equal to "2" by the time you click on a rect. There are many ways to fix this, example below :

```
function renderICD() {
    var totalx=1200;
    var totaly=1000;
    var xOffset = 150;
    var yOffset = 20;

    surface = dojox.gfx.createSurface("icdTab",totalx+2,totaly+2);
    var grid = surface.createGroup();
    var step = 1;
    var xyHolder = {};
    var group = grid.createGroup();

    dojo.forEach([0,1], function(item, ii) {
         var x = (step-1) * (75+85);
         step++;

         var group = grid.createGroup();

         group.createRect({x:xOffset+x+33, y:yOffset+20+90, width: 10, height: 10}).setFill([255, 255, 255, 0.9])
            .setStroke({color:'black' , width:2});


              dojo.connect(group.getEventSource(),"onclick",function(e) {
                       var internal = ii;
                       alert("publishing "+internal);
               //shape was clicked, now do something!
                        });

         grid.createText({x:xOffset+x+33, y:yOffset+20+80, text:ii,align:"middle"})
            .setFill('red')
            .setFont({size: '10px',weight: "bold"});
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I have certain images and drawings to make on the gui to display in a format and also handle events in the surface. i currently use gfx like the above method. Any suggestions to move to other APIs so that this will be much easier?